# Unicode characters not getting displayed correctly on localhost

Tags: python, unicode, localhost

I want to display this character “‾” (U+203E) but this is what I get on the local host: Ã¢â‚¬Â¾
Im using python and this is the code im using:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/file.txt'
        try:
            file_to_open = open(self.path[1:]).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open = "File not found"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

contents of file.txt:

```py
‾
```

Displayed in local host:

```py
Ã¢â‚¬Â¾
```

Any way to properly display Unicode characters?

Comment: The browser doesn't know the encoding. If you want to display the content in the browser, send it as html. If you want to send a file, send the appropriate Content-Type header.

Comment: code `'‾'.encode().decode('latin1')` gives me `'â\x80¾'` which is similar to your output - it may suggest that browser as default treats it as `latin1` or similar encoding. You have to send correct `HTTP header` with information what encoding or what type of file you send.

Comment: You face a **double** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Ã¢â‚¬Â¾' .encode('cp1252') .decode() .encode('cp1252') .decode()` returns `'‾'` (U+203E,  *Overline*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know browser doesn't have to use `utf-8` as default encoding but i.e. `iso8859-2`.

Browser doesn't know what encoding is inside file and you have to use HTTP header to inform it

```
self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
```

---

Minimal working example

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        text = '‾'

        self.send_response(200)

        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")

        self.end_headers()

        #self.wfile.write(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(text.encode('utf-8'))

print('Serving http://localhost:8080')
httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you will send file with HTML then inside file you can use HTML tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Minimal working example

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        text = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
‾
</body>

</html>
'''
        
        self.send_response(200)
        
        self.end_headers()
        
        #self.wfile.write(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(text.encode('utf-8'))

print('Serving http://localhost:8080')
httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```